# jquery javascript this function is not calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, zeroclipboard

I have this java script function:

```
function copyToClipboardCrossbrowser2(text) {
    alert(text);
    $('#Button1').zclip({
        path: '/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: text
    });
}
```

when I make `path: js/ZeroClipboard.swf` , google chrome tells me that this file is not exist. but when I put the `/` it doesn't tell me that it is not working. so the swf is installed.

the alter is printing the correct value. but the copy is not working.

why please?

I already include these:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.zclip.js"></script>
```

#### Note

In another project, I am working with this library, which means my flash player is working

This is the html of the button that has the id `Button`

```
<button type="button" id="Button1" class="copyToBtn" onclick="copyToClipboardCrossbrowser2('00971509396782',this);" title="Copy">
                                Copy Phone Number</button>
```

I am working asp.net 
and this is the code of the button

```
<button type="button" id="Button1" class="copyToBtn" type="button" onclick="copyToClipboardCrossbrowser2('<%#Eval("Telephone")%>',this);"
                                title="Copy">
                                Copy Phone Number</button>
```

#### The id is not changing that is why I gave you the html

Comment: parameters do not match the method

Comment: @SomnathKharat I know that and the good thing is the alert is working. however, I removed the `this` and it is the same

Comment: @SomnathKharat please help

Comment: zclip already binds a click on the given id. you are writing one more click event on it

Comment: @susheel so what should I do please?

Comment: you want only this format or anything is fine ?

Comment: anything working is fine. Also, I tried this function on another project and it is working fine. just on this project, i don't know why. I mean putting the zlip inside a function is not wrong

Comment: it will fire but on second click. the way which you are trying..on first click the zclip is set with the value you passed. on second it executes. but its not a correct way'

Comment: let me test it to check if it is really firing on the second click

Comment: if that case doesn't work. then check if the swf file is working fine.

Comment: it is not working either in the second click. either in the 10 click. pleae help

Comment: @susheel how to check that please? I told you that it is working fine on another project. but I am afraid that I should include more libraries or I include them in the wrong place

Comment: http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf

got to this link and save this. and include in your project. then check if you have flash player. better check the code in chrome it has inbuilt flash player. give as js/ not /js

Comment: I am aware for the flash player, that is why I stated in the question that I can make the copy on other projects which means the flash player is working. and I am using chrome for debugging, there is no error. and I can debug the script.it goes to the correct library

Comment: you gave me an empty link please?

Comment: @susheel please can you access my computer remotely please?

Comment: let me give you example

Answer (score 0):

js fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/6HPuC/**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zclip/1.1.2/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>        
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#Button1").zclip({
            path: 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zclip/1.1.2/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: function() {
                return $(this).data("copy");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" data-copy="<%#Eval('Telephone')%>" id="Button1" class="copyToBtn" title="Copy">Copy Phone Number</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am doing that exactly really. I don't know why it is not working on this project.although it is working on another project. pleaes can you access my computer just for 2 minutes to check your self

Comment: in the jquery.zclip.js there is this line ` if (typeof params == "object" && !params.length) {` it becomes `true`. is that correct or it should become `false` ?

Comment: using teamviewer. it is a small application you can install then access my computer

Comment: i know teamviewer but i am in office ..teamviewer is not allowed.

Comment: when can u come home so you can access please?

Comment: sure...i will help you out. by that time if someone else solves your problem it will be fine.

Comment: I will keep trying and please when you can access please please tell me, it is urgent to me. also, if you can tell me when will u be available will be great

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51190/discussion-between-susheel-and-simeoni-peraparota)

Comment: tell your id password for teamviewer

Comment: My friend, I am waiting for you

Comment: delete that username and password

Comment: where are you, maybe you disconnected?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have used on button click event to bind zClip with button which is Wrong.
When you attach ZClip to button it will automatically handles OnClick event, no need to write on button event

Below is your modified code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Button1').zclip({
            path: '/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: $('#Button1').attr('data-copy')
        });        
    });

</script>
```

And button event will be as below:

```
<button type="button" id="Button1" class="copyToBtn" data-copy="<%#Eval('Telephone')%>" title="Copy">
            Copy Phone Number</button>
```

Comment: my button is inside a listview. when I make a button outside the listview it works fine. but when I put the button inside the listview it stop working

Comment: It is because when you put any control inside data controller its id will be rendered differently like "CPH_Button1".
You can see button ID by inspecting element.

Comment: my friend, i aware for these things, that is why i told you (in bold) that the id is not changing. I checked that in chrome tools f12

Comment: data attribute is invalid. we can use data-* but not just data.(HTML5)

Comment: Thanks susheel for correcting.
@Simeoni Peraparota this is some wired behaviour. it will be better if you provide your full code.